# The grid system does not work as expected, the width of the cell phone screen is much smaller than a minimum size browser

Tags: angular, media-queries, angular-ui-bootstrap

i built web app with angular and I wrote the code so that the app would be fully responsible with mobile usage. (Or so I thought)
I used bootatrep's grid system and media query to make the app fit by minimilizing the google chrome page in order to check that the application did fit.

Yesterday I made an application deployment and saw that it was not responding at all as I expected and the phone screen is much smaller than the smallest screen the web browser allows.
Does anyone have an idea how to arrange it? And how do you avoid such problems in the future?

[Picture to illustrate the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r29a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some solution to test your website directly on your phone before build it to production. 
You can easily debug you local app on your phone. Your phone should be on the same wifi/network.

**First solution :**

```
ng serve --host
```

option as explained in this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1793.

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Find your local ip address (https://lifehacker.com/how-to-find-your-local-and-external-ip-address-5833108)
Navigate to `<local ip adress>:4200` from your phone or other device.

**Second Solution**

There is some software to emulate phone in browser. One of them is this one : https://blisk.io/